# Add/fix links to comments in review queues

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, hyperlinks

When reviewing a post, the comments are shown underneath, which is great, but there's a difference: on the Q&A page, the timestamps (x units of time ago) are clickable and contain a direct link to the comment. On the review pages, the hover works, but it's not clickable.

Since it's sometimes useful to refer to another comment while reviewing, could this be converted into a proper link?

[image]